# superabundance of iterations cluttering data structures

Tags: java, arraylist, io

I want my output to look like this:

```
/home/flavius/data/train/politics/p_0.txt, [L'Etat,, c'est, moi.]
/home/flavius/data/train/science/s_0.txt, [If, I, have, seen, further, it, is, by, standing, on, the, shoulders, of, giants.]
/home/flavius/data/train/atheism/a_0.txt, [Gott, ist, tot.]
/home/flavius/data/train/sports/s_1.txt, [You, miss, 100%, of, the, shots, you, don't, take.]
```

But at this juncture, it looks like the following, with four extra lines appended to the front:

```
/home/flavius/data/train/atheism/a_0.txt
/home/flavius/data/train/politics/p_0.txt
/home/flavius/data/train/science/s_0.txt
/home/flavius/data/train/sports/s_1.txt
/home/flavius/data/train/politics/p_0.txt, [L'Etat,, c'est, moi.]
/home/flavius/data/train/science/s_0.txt, [If, I, have, seen, further, it, is, by, standing, on, the, shoulders, of, giants.]
/home/flavius/data/train/atheism/a_0.txt, [Gott, ist, tot.]
/home/flavius/data/train/sports/s_1.txt, [You, miss, 100%, of, the, shots, you, don't, take.]
```

My question is, why does it add those first four lines?

The program reads in different files under four directories and then for each file creates an entry in a hashmap with the file name as the key and all the words contained in that file stored as an array list.

This is the code, it's pretty straightforward. Maybe someone can spot where I went wrong.

```
public class FileDictCreateur 
{
    static String PATH = "/home/flavius/data/train";

    static Map<File, ArrayList<String> > fileDict = new HashMap<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        //each of the diferent categories
        String[] categories = { "/atheism", "/politics", "/science", "/sports"};

        //cycle through all categories once to populate the global dict
        for(int cycle = 0; cycle <= 3; cycle++)
        {
            String general_data_partition = PATH + categories[cycle];

            File directory = new File( general_data_partition );
            iterateDirectory( directory );  
        }

        for (Map.Entry entry : fileDict.entrySet()) 
        {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ", " + entry.getValue());
        }
    }

    private static void iterateDirectory(File directory) throws IOException 
    {
        for (File file : directory.listFiles()) 
        {
            if (file.isDirectory()) 
            {
                iterateDirectory(directory);
            } 
            else 
            {
                System.out.println(file);

                String line; 
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader( file ));

                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
                {
                    String[] words = line.split(" ");//those are your words

                    //populate_globo_dict(words);

                    create_file_dict( file, words );

                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void create_file_dict( File file, String[] words ) throws IOException
    {   

        if (!fileDict.containsKey(file))
        {
            ArrayList document_words = new ArrayList<String>();

            String word;

            for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) 
            {
                word = words[i];

                document_words.add(word);
            }
            fileDict.put(file, document_words);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in `iterateDirectory()` inside the `else` you have `System.out.println(file)`.

This means that every time you reach a file rather than a directory, its name will be printed.

Answer (score 1):

From this for loop:

```
for (int cycle = 0; cycle <= 3; cycle++) {
        String general_data_partition = PATH + categories[cycle];
        File directory = new File(general_data_partition);
        System.out.println(directory);
        iterateDirectory(directory);
 }
```

Remove the following statement: `System.out.println(directory);` which prints the directory name.